# plot.lm Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Tags: r, plot, regression, linear-regression, lm

I have the following regression model with transformations:

```
fit <- lm( I(NewValue ^ (1 / 3)) ~ I(CurrentValue ^ (1 / 3)) + Age + Type - 1,
           data = dataReg)
plot(fit)
```

But `plot` gives me the following error:

```
Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

Any ideas about what I am doing wrong?

**Note**: `summary`, `predict`, and `residuals` all work correctly.

Comment: Can you post `summary fit`?

Comment: @Christoph I was about to post the summary, but the answer of Zheyuan Li complements my post sufficiently well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is actually quite a interesting observation. In fact, among all 6 plots supported by `plot.lm`, only the Q-Q plot fails in this case. Consider the following reproducible example:

```
x <- runif(20)
y <- runif(20)
fit <- lm(I(y ^ (1/3)) ~ I(x ^ (1/3)))
## only `which = 2L` (QQ plot) fails; `which = 1, 3, 4, 5, 6` all work
stats:::plot.lm(fit, which = 2L)
```

Inside `plot.lm`, the Q-Q plot is simply produced as follow:

```
rs <- rstandard(fit)  ## standardised residuals
qqnorm(rs)  ## fine
## inside `qqline(rs)`
yy <- quantile(rs, c(0.25, 0.75))
xx <- qnorm(c(0.25, 0.75))
slope <- diff(yy)/diff(xx)
int <- yy[1L] - slope * xx[1L]
abline(int, slope)  ## this fails!!!
```

> Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

**So this is purely a problem of `abline` function!** Note:

```
is.object(int)
# [1] TRUE

is.object(slope)
# [1] TRUE
```

i.e., both `int` and `slope` has class attribute (*read `?is.object`; it is a very efficient way to check whether an object has class attribute*). What class?

```
class(int)
# [1] AsIs

class(slope)
# [1] AsIs
```

**This is the result of using `I()`. Precisely, they inherits such class from `rs` and further from the response variable. That is, if we use `I()` on response, the RHS of the model formula, we get this behaviour.**

You can do a few experiment here:

```
abline(as.numeric(int), as.numeric(slope))  ## OK
abline(as.numeric(int), slope)  ## OK
abline(int, as.numeric(slope))  ## fails!!
abline(int, slope)  ## fails!!
```

**So `abline(a, b)` is very sensitive to whether the first argument `a` has class attribute or not.**

Why? Because `abline` can accept a linear model object with "lm" class. Inside `abline`:

```
if (is.object(a) || is.list(a)) {
    p <- length(coefa <- as.vector(coef(a)))
```

**If `a` has a class, `abline` is assuming it as a model object (regardless whether it is really is!!!), then try to use `coef` to obtain coefficients. The check being done here is fairly not robust; we can make `abline` fail rather easily:**

```
plot(0:1, 0:1)
a <- 0  ## plain numeric
abline(a, 1)  ## OK
class(a) <- "whatever"  ## add a class
abline(a, 1)  ## oops, fails!!!
```

> Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

**So here is the conclusion: avoid using `I()` on your response variable in the model formula.** It is OK to have `I()` on covariates, but not on response. `lm` and most generic functions won't have trouble dealing with this, but `plot.lm` will.

Comment: Indeed the Residual - Fitted plot was produced correctly, while the problem was encountered when drawing the Q-Q plot. When I avoid I() everything runs smoothly.